# Oracle select dates that are not returned in the data set

Tags: sql, database, oracle

What i am looking for is given a start and end date i want to return dates that are not in the data set. For example, lets say for the month of January in 2018 i want to return all dates that are not in the list.

So for the given query:

```
select distinct to_date(date_field, 'dd-mon-yyyy') from tbl_main where date_field >= '01-JAN-2018' and date_field <= '31-JAN-2018'
```

Result:

```
02-JAN-2018
05-JAN-2018
```

Now i have query to list days of the month of january:

```
select to_date('01.01.2018','dd-mm-yyyy')+level-1 as dt
from dual 
connect by level <= TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(to_date('01.01.2018','dd.mm.yyyy')),'DD')
```

Result:

```
01-JAN-18
02-JAN-18
...
31-JAN-18
```

So based on this i tried running following which didn't work:

```
select dt from(
select to_date('01.01.2018','dd-mm-yyyy')+level-1 as dt
from dual 
connect by level <= 
TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(to_date('01.01.2018','dd.mm.yyyy')),'DD')) 
where dt not in (select distinct to_date(date_field, 'dd.mm.yyyy') from 
tbl_main where date_field >= '01-JAN-2018' and x_datetime_insert <= '01-JAN- 
2018') order by dt
```

Based on what is returned running queries individually i feel above query should work. Just to be clear i expect the result to be all dates in january other than following:

```
02-JAN-2018
05-JAN-2018
```

Expected Result:

```
01-JAN-2018
03-JAN-2018
04-JAN-2018
06-JAN-2018
...
31-JAN-2018
```

Any help would be much appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: I see you have typo in your SQL causing the unexpected result, otherwise you are on right track. Change `01.10.2018` to  `01.01.2018` in your select dual.

Comment: @AmithKumar Yes you are correct but also needed to do steps from my answer below to get expected result. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: You are doing a lot of unnecessary work. For example, in the subquery used in the `IN` condition, you do not need to `select DISTINCT`, a simple `select` will do the same job, and much faster. `DISTINCT` only wasted (a lot of) time there. It also seems your `date_field` is in `varchar2` data type, despite its name. Why? That will cause lots of problems - invalid data may be accepted, queries will be much slower, harder to write, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was i was using yyyy instead of yy. Once i changed that i got the expected result. Will leave post for anyone in future trying to solve similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select to_date('01.01.2018','dd.mm.yyyy')+level-1 as dt
from dual 
connect by level <= TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(to_date('01.01.2018','dd.mm.yyyy')),'DD')
minus
select to_date(date_field, 'dd.mm.yyyy') 
from tbl_main 
where date_field >= '01-JAN-2018'
and x_datetime_insert <= '01-JAN-2018'
order by dt
```